# When a batch-program will go to next line?

Tags: windows, batch, batch-file, rar

I have a batch file

```
for /f "tokens=2 delims==" %%a in ('wmic OS Get localdatetime /value') do set "dt=%%a"
set "YY=%dt:~2,2%" & set "YYYY=%dt:~0,4%" & set "MM=%dt:~4,2%" & set "DD=%dt:~6,2%"
set "HH=%dt:~8,2%" & set "Min=%dt:~10,2%" & set "Sec=%dt:~12,2%"

set "my_date=%YYYY%%MM%%DD%" & set "time=%HH%%Min%"

set "minFiles=10"

setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

rar a -t -rr D:\Backup\Arch\Backup_%_my_date%.rar D:\Backup\Backup.bak

for /f %%A in ('dir "D:\Backup\Arch\*.rar" /a-d-s-h /b ^| find /v /c ""') do if %%A leq %minFiles% goto :eof
:loop
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('dir /b /a-d /t:w /o:d "D:\Backup\Arch\*.rar"') do (
    del "%%a"
    goto :breakLoop
    )
:breakLoop
pause
for /f %%A in ('dir "D:\Backup\Arch\*.rar" /a-d-s-h /b ^| find /v /c ""') do if %%A gtr %minFiles% goto :loop
```

It is supposed to rar a file and then check if there is more than 10 files in folder delete oldest file. It works well until in folder D:\Backup\Arch\ are 10 rar files.
But if in folder are 10 rar files and I start *.bat I get a new rar file in D:\Backup\Arch\ and now they are 11. It's supposed to go to next line delete one file if there are 11, but it doesn't delete. Why ?
rar is taking 2 or 3 hours.

When program is here

```
rar a -t -rr D:\Backup\Arch\Backup_%_my_date%.rar D:\Backup\Backup.bak
```

and it's archiving file when does it go to next line

```
for /f %%A in ('dir "D:\Backup\Arch\*.rar" /a-d-s-h /b ^| find /v /c ""') do if %%A leq %minFiles% goto :eof
```

It goes when rar is finished or right after command rar is send ?
How I can make program to go to the next line right after rar is finished ?

If I start a different bat with this part of code it works perfect and delete files

```
for /f %%A in ('dir "D:\Backup\Arch\*.rar" /a-d-s-h /b ^| find /v /c ""') do if %%A leq %minFiles% goto :eof
:loop
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('dir /b /a-d /t:w /o:d "D:\Backup\Arch\*.rar"') do (
    del "%%a"
    goto :breakLoop
    )
:breakLoop
pause
for /f %%A in ('dir "D:\Backup\Arch\*.rar" /a-d-s-h /b ^| find /v /c ""') do if %%A gtr %minFiles% goto :loop
```

Comment: You want somebody to debug the batch file, can't you ask the guy that wrote it?

Comment: As your backup file names contain the date in a sortable format, why don't you simply sort by names backwards (`dir /B /O-N`) and use `for /f "skip=%minfiles% delims="` ?

Comment: @LotPings you think he wrote that?  and btw changing a line of a program can potentially ruin it. What makes you think that making that change is not going to ruin the whole thing, he may have to change other lines to adjust for that.  And I doubt that'd fix his problem anyway

Comment: you are lucky to have got an answer, try what lotpings wrote in his answer

Comment: @barlop - it doesn't matter who wrote it. It is a reasonable question

Comment: @lx07 I didn't say it was or wasn't a reasonable question.  It does look like a question that is not useful to the database and only useful to that one particular user that asked it.

Answer (score 2):

As per my comment, I suggest to:

- use for /f with the skip option
- and parse dir output sorted reverse by name  `dir /B /A-D /O-N`
- BTW you created a variable `my_date` but tried to use the nonexistent `%_my_date%`

---

```
:: Q:\Test\2019\06\14\SU_1448654.cmd
@Echo off & setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
for /f "tokens=2 delims==" %%a in ('wmic OS Get localdatetime /value') do set "dt=%%a"
set "my_date=%dt:~0,8%
set "minFiles=10"

rar a -t -rr D:\Backup\Arch\Backup_%my_date%.rar D:\Backup\Backup.bak

for /f "skip=%minFiles% delims=" %%a in ('dir /B /A-d /O-N "D:\Backup\Arch\Backup_*.rar"') do (
    Echo del "%%a"
)
pause
```

If the output looks OK, remove the `Echo` in front of the `del` command